# CosmoDB SQL - Select sub document properties

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a CosmoDB document that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "something",
    "object": {
        "a": {
            "property": "xxx"
        },
        "b": {
            "property": "yyyy"
        }
    }
}
```

For the sake of a data migration, I need to SELECT from this document the follwing informations: *id, property.*

The problem I am having is that *object* can have a variable number of sub-objects with different name to select from (eg: a, b, d, e, .. z)

Does someone know how to acheive this without writing a Stored Procedure?

Comment: Have you tried doing a self-join? Aside from that: this seems to be a sub-optimal schema for what you're trying to do, as the `a` and `b` sub-objects are differently named. Or... if you're using `a` and `b` as *names* of those sub-objects, you've now embedded actual data values into property names (an anti-pattern). Might make things easier to rework the data design a bit...

Comment: self-join does not return anything...  know the document structure looks bad but is what it is :)

Comment: "*self join does not return anything*" - it would help if you edited your question to show your query, expected results, and actual results. Right now, you've only shown some data.

Comment: As far as the document structure: the issue is as I stated (embedding data as an element name). It may be that you need to create a specific materialized view that's properly queryable.